# Filter out CSV values after a space in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So my goal is to read CSV file created by a Geocoder that has annoyingly put string values with a space and latitude or longitude values… I could go through all of these excel cells and split them manually, but I would really like to read CSV instead and just use the space as the delimiter and filter out all of the string values. I know how to import CSV, and even how to specify space as the delimiter I think I… But what I don't understand is how to filter out all of the string values and save only the numeric values in a brand new Excel sheet. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is the code I have so far to delimit the white space:
pd.read_csv('file.csv',delim_whitespace=True)

Comment: 1. Some cutout of your CSV would _really really really_ help. 2. Do you have pandas?

Comment: You can refer regex/pandas for this.

Comment: Can you show us an example of your CSV and of the code you've written?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes, sorry. For some reason it cut off the end of my message… I added my code I have so far now. I do use pandas.

Comment: And the CSV? Where is that?

Comment: Try to fix string values in CSV first, then just read CSV with correct values.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it's on the university drive. I currently live in Florida where we have no power anywhere, working as an adjunct professor in information systems. So it's on the university server which has no power. The code reads like this however: Georgia 64.66  Florida 93.95 Texas 24.74 so it is simply string value separated by space from numeric values.

Comment: @user18139 So what do you want as the result?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I would like to filter out all string values and output only the numeric values into either a CSV or excel sheet. These are geocodes or latitude longitude points, so I only need those to put them on a map

Comment: @user18139 I got it. You can take a look at my answer and use it if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to read your CSV, [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to select only numeric columns, and save only numeric columns to a CSV using [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
df.select_dtypes(['float']).to_csv('file.csv')
```

If your file has no headers, you'll need to add `header=None` when reading the CSV.

---

```
df

     a  b    c
0  1.0  0  foo
1  2.0  0  NaN
2  1.0  1  bar
3  1.0  1  foo
4  NaN  1  baz
5  3.0  1  foo
6  3.0  1  bar

df.select_dtypes(['float'])

     a
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  1.0
3  1.0
4  NaN
5  3.0
6  3.0
```

If, for some reason, you have integeral columns you want to save, change `float` to `number`:

```
df.select_dtypes(['number'])

     a  b
0  1.0  0
1  2.0  0
2  1.0  1
3  1.0  1
4  NaN  1
5  3.0  1
6  3.0  1
```

And just chain a `.to_csv` call.

Comment: Just answer it honestly perfect. Going to selected as the answer because of that. But I do have an additional question. What if instead of white space it is comma delimited? Do I change it from white space to comma?

Comment: @user18139 Remove delim_whitespace=True and instead add delimiter=","

Answer (score 0):

If you get the data separated as you should you can use this:

```
df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dropna(axis=1)
```

and you can add `.to_csv('your_file_name.csv')` at the end.

Comment: Converting and dropping seems wasteful. Selection would be simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Didn't know about `number` option +1

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ so in your answer, you are reading from CSV, taking the entire file, and then just filtering out the values you want… But he is suggesting converting the files and then dropping them? That seems confusing

Comment: @user18139 Converting the columns, not the files. The string columns when converted become NaN and are dropped. This is dangerous since your original data might also have NaNs.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I sent you an email to the email address on your profile. It would probably be easier to contact me back there… I follow the exact instructions but it wouldn't separate the data points into individual columns. They are all just crammed into one single data frame column… and it also won't select float values either I don't know why

Comment: @user18139 Sure. I'm a bit busy right now, but I'll get back to you as soon as I can.